# weex data change to update to child component

Tags: vue.js, components, weex

```
<template>
    <topView viewInfo="cardInfo"></topView>
    <bottomView viewInfo="cardInfo"></bottomView>
<template>
<script>
     module.exports = {
        data: {
          viewInfo:{
             attr0:value0,
             attr1:value1
          }
       },
       mounted:function(){
          getDataFromServer();
       },
       methods:{
          getDataFromServer:function(){
            var me = this;
            var httpRequest = Service.getViewInfo();
            httpRequest.on("success",function(data){
               me.viewInfo.attr2 = data.info.attr2;
               me.viewInfo.attr3 = data.info.attr3;
               me.viewInfo.attr4 = data.info.attr4;

           });
           httpRequest.send();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

topView.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <text>{viewInfo.attr0}</text>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in getItems">
        <text>{item.text}</text>
        <text>{item.info}</text>
  </div>
  <text>{viewInfo.attr1}</text>
</div>
<template>

<script>
 module.exports = {
    data: {
      itemInfo:[
          {text:'text 0',info:"****"},
          {text:'text 1',info:"****"},
          {text:'text 2',info:"****"}
      ]
    },
    props:{
        viewInfo:{}
    },
    computed:{
      getItems:function(){
        this.itemInfo[0].info = this.viewInfo.attr2 +" point";
        this.itemInfo[1].info = this.viewInfo.attr3 +" point";
        this.itemInfo[2].info = this.viewInfo.attr4 +" point";

        return itemInfo;
      }
    },
    methods:{

       }
    }
</script>
```

when i get data from server,and add some attr value to viewInfo. the child comphonent can update direct value.the compute values can't update relation to props data from parent component.

need some help.how can i update compute items value when i update parent component "viewInfo" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Vue cannot detect the changes when you directly set an item with the index*, i.e. `this.itemInfo[0].info = this.viewInfo.attr2 +" point"` **Is not reactive**.

Use `Vue.set` instead, for the above:

```js
// create a new item
var newItem = Object.assign({}, this.itemInfo[0], { info: this.viewInfo.attr2 +" point" })
// set the new item to the specific index
this.$set(this.itemInfo, 0, newItem)
```

You can read more about [List Rendering Caveats here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

Comment: thanks @Psidom,follow your advise,i also modidfy object set attr method at ` 
   getDataFromServer function,:

 getDataFromServer:function(){
            var me = this;
            var httpRequest = Service.getViewInfo();
            httpRequest.on("success",function(data){
           
               me.$set(me.viewInfo, 'attr2', data.info.attr2);
               me.$set(me.viewInfo, 'attr3', data.info.attr3);
               me.$set(me.viewInfo, 'attr4', data.info.attr4);

           });
           httpRequest.send();
      }    `